Convert the number formats (Decimal - Hexadecimal - Octal) to Decimal
Problem statement:
Write a program called multi_input.cpp that prompts the user to enter several integers in any combination of octal, decimal, or hexadecimal, using the 0 and 0x base prefixes; interprets the numbers correctly; and converts them to decimal form.
Then your program should output the values in properly spaced columns like this:



Initial value
Type
Converts
Result value
Type




0x43
hexadecimal
converts to
67
decimal


0123
octal
converts to
83
decimal


65
decimal
converts to
65
decimal



Solution:
#include <iostream> // cout, cin, cerr
#include <iomanip> // setw
#include <cctype> // isxdigit
#include <string> // string, stoi, to_string
#include <vector> // vector
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::cerr;
using std::setw;
using std::isxdigit;
using std::string;
using std::stoi;
using std::to_string;
using std::vector;

bool is_int(const string& str)
{
    // avoid letters conflict with hexadecimal letters (ABCDEFabcdef)
    if (str.size() == 1 && isxdigit(str[0]))
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (const char& ch : str)
    {
        if (!(isxdigit(ch) || ch == 'x' || ch == 'X'))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool is_oct(const string& str)
{
    for (const char& ch : str)
    {
        if (ch < '0' || ch > '7')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter several integers in any combination of octal, decimal, or hexadecimal by using:\n"
        << "nothing for decimal\n"
        << "0 base prefix for octal\n"
        << "0x base prefixe for hexadecimal\n\n";

    constexpr int OCTAL_BASE = 8;
    constexpr int HEXADECIMAL_BASE = 16;

    vector<string> inputs;

    // get the input stream

    for (string s; cin >> s;)
    {
        inputs.push_back(s);
    }

    // start conversion form (octal - decimal - hexadecimal) to deciaml

    for (const string& s : inputs) // iterate through the vector "inputs"
    {
        if (is_int(s))
            // if it is an integer of any format of (octal - decimal - hexadecimal) numbers
        {
            if (s[0] == '0' && isdigit(s[1]))
                // if it is an octal
            {

                if (is_oct(s)) // check if it is an octal [0 : 7]
                {
                    cout << setw(5) << s << setw(25) << " octal converts to "
                        << setw(3) << to_string(stoi(s, nullptr, OCTAL_BASE)) << setw(7) << " decimal";
                }
                else
                {
                    cerr << "the input " << s << " can not be represented as an octal number";
                }

            }
            else if (s[0] == '0' && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X'))
                // if it is an hexadecimal
            {
                cout << setw(5) << s << setw(25) << " hexadecimal converts to "
                    << setw(3) << to_string(stoi(s, nullptr, HEXADECIMAL_BASE)) << setw(7) << " decimal";
            }
            else
                // if it is a decimal
            {
                cout << setw(5) << s << setw(25) << " decimal converts to "
                    << setw(3) << s << setw(7) << " decimal";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "the input " << s << " is not a/an (octal - decimal - hexadecimal) number";
        }

        cout << '\n';

    }

    return 0;
}


Have you considered the case when the input is just “0”?

UI
Make sure you inform the user on how to enter the input. It seems that you are requiring the numbers one line each, then followed by an empty line. That should be made clear.
Comments
#include <iostream> // cout, cin, cerr

IDE's should be able to find the functionality used from any included library or library header. Moreover, this will require you and every other developer to keep the comments and code consistent. Experience learns that this never - or almost never - happens.
// start conversion form (octal - decimal - hexadecimal) to deciaml

Whenever you see a comment such as this then it probably is best to put the part of the program that is described in a separate function. Minimum input handling is fine in main, but please put the actual functionality in functions or of course classes. Later on you'll learn how to write unit tests for those functions.
// iterate through the vector "inputs"

For each part of the program it should be clear what it does. If it isn't clear from code, it should be described by a comment. However, this is clearly covered by the code; all programmers will understand how iteration through a collection such as vector<string> works.
// if it is an integer of any format of (octal - decimal - hexadecimal) numbers

This is part of the function description, so it should be in a comment above the function, [edit] preferably in a format so the API documentation can be extracted, usually DoxyGen for C++ code.
Code
bool is_int(const string& str)

This method is not filtering out all possible badly formatted integers. For instance, xXx would be considered a number value, while it isn't. It's also a horridly bad movie in my opinion. It is however probably better to write three functions is_octal, is_decimal and is_hex. That splits up the problem nicely, and is_int would be much easier to write: return is_octal(s) || is_decimal(s) || is_hex(s), if it is even still needed.
cout << setw(5) << s << setw(25) << " octal converts to "
                    << setw(3) << to_string(stoi(s, nullptr, OCTAL_BASE)) << setw(7) << " decimal";

I'd make sure that you convert the octet to an int first, and then output the value of the integer. Please do not do this inline with the code that outputs the value, as this will make the code hard to find - even if it is just a call to stoi.
// if it is a decimal

... prints decimal

Yes, but because of the failing is_int this may print out wrong values.
Remarks
Code is generally fine; well indented and easy to read. Variables and function names are OK. I'd not put comments between if statements and the code block, but as you do it consistently this isn't a huge issue. I'd also put a \n after printing a line to std::err.

Correctness aside, a style comment.
Your for loop has an else that feels better suited to a guard that gets the exceptional situation out of the way first. This lets you unindent the main logic of your loop.
Also, factoring out the printing of the newline feels like it isn't worth the confusion that might stem from it.
    for (const string& s : inputs) // iterate through the vector "inputs"
    {
        if (!is_int(s))
        {
            cerr << "the input " << s << " is not a/an (octal - decimal - hexadecimal) number\n";
            continue;
        }

        if (s[0] == '0' && isdigit(s[1]))
            // if it is an octal
        {
            if (!is_oct(s)) {
                cerr << "the input " << s << " can not be represented as an octal number\n";
                continue;
            }

            cout << setw(5) << s << setw(25) << " octal converts to "
                 << setw(3) << to_string(stoi(s, nullptr, OCTAL_BASE)) << setw(7) << " decimal\n";
        }
        else if (s[0] == '0' && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X'))
            // if it is an hexadecimal
        {
            cout << setw(5) << s << setw(25) << " hexadecimal converts to "
                 << setw(3) << to_string(stoi(s, nullptr, HEXADECIMAL_BASE)) << setw(7) << " decimal\n";
        }
        else
            // if it is a decimal
        {
            cout << setw(5) << s << setw(25) << " decimal converts to "
                 << setw(3) << s << setw(7) << " decimal\n";
        }
    }
}

I would probably also leverage including <cctype> to change:
s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X'

To:
std::tolower(s[1]) == 'x'


Don't forget that std::tolower() takes a small positive int, not a char!

It's best to check if the length of the string s is at least 2 before checking if s[1] is an x or an X:
(s.length() >= 2 && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X'))
Additionally, it would be good to handle the special case where the input could be: "0x" or "0" or "": you would want to indicate that the number is 0 then or is simply invalid?

That's really not necessary, given the actual code s[0] == '0' && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X') - if the length is zero, then s[0] is '\0' and the RHS is not evaluated; if the length is one, then s[1] is '\0' which is neither 'x' nor 'X'.  There's no need to traverse the whole length of the string to preempt that.

std::isxdigit(str[0]) is wrong.  The <cctype> functions all accept small positive integers, but you're passing a possibly-signed char value, which could widen to a negative int and result in undefined behaviour.
We need to represent the value as an unsigned char before that (positive) value is widened to int:
std::isxdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[0]))

The same applies to the uses of std::isdigit() of course.

There's a lot of duplication for the different number base inputs.  I think it's better to use std::stoi() with 0 as its "base" argument, which will parse octal, decimal or hex - don't forget to use the "pos" argument to validate whether the input was completely parsed.
Then we can simply determine the input base using std::string::starts_with() giving a single code path for the printing:
std::size_t end;
auto value = std::stoi(s, &end, 0);
if (s.empty() || end != s.size()) {
    std::cerr << "Input \"" << s "\" is not a valid number\n";
    continue;
}
auto base = s.starts_with("0x") || s.starts_with("0X") ? "hexadecimal"
          : s.starts_with('0') && s.size() > 1 ? "octal"
          : "decimal";
std::cout << std::setw(5) << s << std::setw(25) << ' ' << base << " converts to "
          << std::setw(3) << value << std::setw(7) << " decimal";

